# Property [associated_occupation] does not exist on this collection instance. - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, phpword

I would like to store a database value into the variable.  For some reason It's not working as expected.  Below is the code in controller:

```
 public function show(Word $word)
{
    //

    $curriculum = Curriculum::findOrFail($word->id);
   // dd($curriculum->id);
    session(['key' => $curriculum->id]);
    $knowledge = Knowledge::where('curriculum_id','=', $word->id)->get();
    $information = Information::where('curriculum_id','=', $word->id)->get();
    $practical = Practical::where('curriculum_id','=',$word->id)->get();
    $work = Work::where('curriculum_id','=',$word->id)->get();
    $entry = Entry::where('curriculum_id','=',$word->id)->get();
    $assessment = Assessment::where('curriculum_id','=',$word->id)->get();
    $parts = Part::where('curriculum_id','=',$word->id)->get();
    $occupurpose = Occupurpose::where('curriculum_id','=',$word->id)->get();
    $occutask = Occutask::where('curriculum_id','=',$word->id)->get();
    $taskdetail = Taskdetail::where('curriculum_id','=',$word->id)->get();
    $purposekm = Purposekm::where('curriculum_id','=',$word->id)->get();
    $guidedtopic = Guidetopic::where('curriculum_id','=',$word->id)->get();
    $purposepms = Purposepm::where('curriculum_id','=',$word->id)->get();
    $purposewem = Purposewem::where('curriculum_id','=',$word->id)->get();
    $guidedpmstopics = Guidedpmstopic::where('curriculum_id','=',$word->id)->get();
    $guidedwemstopics = Guidedwemstopic::where('curriculum_id','=',$word->id)->get();



    $wordTest = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
    $newSection = $wordTest->addSection();

    $SectionHeading = "SECTION 1:  CURRICULUM SUMMARY";
    $newSection->addText($SectionHeading);

    $topicHeading = "1. Occupational Information";
    $newSection->addText($topicHeading);
    $subTopic = "1.1 Associated Occupation";
    $newSection->addText($subTopic);
    $newSection->addText($knowledge->associated_occupation);
    $occupationTopic = "1.2 Occupation or Specialisation Addressed by this Curriculum";
    $newSection->addText($occupationTopic);
    $newSection->addText($knowledge->specialisation);
    $alternativeTopic = "1.3 Alternative Titles used by Industry";
    $newSection->addText($alternativeTopic);
    $newSection->addText($knowledge->alternative_title);

    $objectWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($wordTest,'Word2007');
    try {
        $objectWriter->save(storage_path('TestWordFile.docx'));
    } catch(Exception $e) {
    }

    return response()->download(storage_path('TestWordFile.docx'));
}
```

When I do dd of the curriculum id and the knowledge result I get correct feedback.  Now I would like to store the column

> associated_occupation
>   into the variable called newSection but I get the error mentioned on the subject.  I also tried
>   `$newSection->addText($knowledge->select('associated_occupation'));` instead of `$newSection->addText($knowledge->associated_occupation);`

Please assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access a property of a collection:

```
$knowledge = Knowledge::where('curriculum_id','=', $word->id)->get();
```

The above will give you a collection of results that have the `curriculum_id` as `$word->id`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#retrieving-results

> The get method returns an Illuminate\Support\Collection containing the results where each result is an instance of the PHP StdClass object.

So when you do:

```
$newSection->addText($knowledge->associated_occupation);
```

The `$knowledge->associated_occupation` is looking for `associated_occupation` on a collection of results rather than a specific `Knowledge`

Change your query to:

```
$knowledge = Knowledge::where('curriculum_id','=', $word->id)->first();
```

To get the first `Knowledge` that has it's `curriculum_id` as `$word->id`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#retrieving-results

> If you just need to retrieve a single row from the database table, you
>   may use the first method. This method will return a single StdClass
>   object:

Or filter the collection and pick a specific one